# Cached object in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug

I'll start with the problem :

1. I'm changing the content of an object literal. (*changing the properties values*)
2. The Firebug console (at first clicks) shows the *correct* values.
3. But after a while, it get stuck on a specific value and stop from changing.

(*notice : the `stringify` representation of the object - Always shows the correct values*)

And here are the Details:

1. I select a `street` in the `textbox` (it should set the `StreetText` value in the object)
2. I look at the `console` (wide line) and press the last line , looking at the *street text*.

At first it's OK. In the second try, after I choose another street, it stays on the old value.

However, when I press refresh (on the object), it shows me the correct street name.

What is going on here?

[image]

My object is a regular object literal :

```
  var obj =
            {
                getData: function ()
                {

                    obj.CountryId = $(".ddlCountry").val() || "";
                    obj.CountryText = $(".ddlCountry  :selected").text() || "";
                    obj.StateId = $(".ddlState:visible").val() || "";
                    obj.StateText = $(".ddlState:visible  :selected").text() || "";
                    obj.CityId = $(".hfDataIdCity").val() || "";
                    obj.CityText = $(".hfDataTextCity").val() || "";
                    obj.StreetId = $(".hfDataIdStreet").val() || "";
                    obj.StreetText = $(".hfDataTextStreet").val() || "";
                }
        }
```

and the display on the console is made by onclicking the button :

```
 obj.getData();
 console.log(obj);
```

Why I'm not seeing the correct values ? ( only after refresh....)

p.s. :
ff: 14.0.1
fb:1.10.6

and the cache is turned off

[image]

Comment: If you're using any of jQuery's AJAX methods, you'll probably need to specify the `cache` option to be `false`. I would guess that the browser's just caching the old request to save bandwidth.

Comment: Posting the code you use when you make the request would be helpful.

Comment: @zzzzBov sorry for asking , but how does it related ? I do see the currect values on the STRINGIFY object. which means the AJAX HAS ALREADY COMPLETED AND UPDATED THE PROPERTY VALUE.  ( and I do use cache:false when doing ajax). if there were a problem with ajax async  or cache , the STRINGIFY would have ALSO show me the old value.

Comment: So it's probably a Firebug issue. Since you've demonstrated using `.stringify()` that your program code is correct, then I'd imagine you'd want to use different developer tools, or file a bug report for Firebug, or both.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, as nice as it is to see your clever animation, it's less useful than seeing the code that actually makes the request. If you've made an error in how your AJAX requests are handled, you could be throwing out your new values in favor of the older values.

Comment: Why don't you turn off firebug caching? Like so -> 
http://old.nabble.com/Add-a-%22disable-cache%22-feature-to-Firebug-td21647907.html

Comment: @IamStalker it does turned off :-)

Comment: @zzzzBov thanks for reply. I dont have any ajax errors. and as I was saying the issue is way after the ajax callback.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, http://superuser.com/questions/23134/how-to-turn-off-the-firefox-cache

Comment: @IamStalker Im always working with cache=off . I added this info to my question. Thanks for replying :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, "I don't have any ajax errors" - just because it doesn't throw an error doesn't mean you didn't make a mistake. Let us decide if you've messed up, or if there's a bug in the system. If you want help you have to be willing to help yourself. Otherwise, I'm voting to close, as you seem to be unwilling to add enough information to answer this question properly.

Comment: @zzzzBov ok let it go. once you  realize  that both stringify and console.log are executed **at the same time**  ( way after the ajax callback)  which actually fills the autocomplete - if you notice - and they both have different result - it will all be alright. It must be a FB bug. thanks for replying.

Comment: @zzzzBov here is the code where it happens.http://i.stack.imgur.com/foPss.jpg

Comment: What if you do not edit the street but the city (just to see the edited value directly in the console, not only in the DOM view)
If you see the object was changed in the console but not in the DOM view it might be a bug with the DOM viewport (cached maybe, not updated properly, a feature that doesn't make sense for us here)
If the console logs the "wrong" value it might be a much stranger problem, maybe the javascript being faster on reading the object than jQuery on updating it's values from the html properly.

Did you tried to set a timeout before reading the obj.values, just to be sure?

Comment: I believe it has to be a firebug issue because when he refreshes the object another ajax request is not triggered meaning the javascript already had the data! The caching is probably applied by firebug's object browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use console.dir(obj) for objects not console.log(obj), you are getting a string of the object by doing that so updating it will still work in your code but not show in the console. Strings are immutable, so no property update wil show in your console. Tip: Use watch expressions in chrome debugger.